# Android AVD Black Screen

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I just downloaded Android Studio and am completely lost. I have tried to get the Android Virtual Device working but my laptop processor (i3) seems to not be working and takes a very long time to load and does not load the android correctly. Any help is appreciated.I have completed the steps to create a virtual device but when I click the 'play' button, a black phone comes out without the features.

Comment: post your logs in question.

Comment: try installing an additional sdk or two and target them insteadl.  KitKat android 4.4 / sdk 19 seems to work very well for me for most dev...